# Why are exponents not associative?

Tags: exponentiation, associativity

I ran into something that seemed odd to me today: exponents are not associative. The following equation sums that up:

$$
    10 * 2^{5x} \not\equiv  20^{5x}
$$

Why is this the case? Is there some way to combine the "10" and the "2"?

**Goal:** The reason I ask this question is I am interested in reducing the amount of operations a program will have to perform in order to compute the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HINT:

$$a^x\cdot b^x= (a\cdot b)^x$$ for positive real $a,b$ and real $x$

but $$a\cdot b^x\ne (a\cdot b)^x$$  in general

In fact if finite $a\cdot b\ne0$, $$a\cdot b^x= (a\cdot b)^x\implies a^{x-1}=1$$

$\displaystyle\implies $ either $a=1,$ or $x-1=0$ or $a=-1,x-1$ is even